# PropertyGrid Control depth

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

Is it possible to show **all** member and submember **values** of an object in a PropertyGrid control?

After one level only the member type name is shown instead of a new node with the member's value.

Comment: As far as I know this is only  posible with 3rd party controls.

Comment: If you see a type name in PropertyGrid then that's a sign that you'll need a TypeConverter to convert an object to a readable string and back.  Or a UITypeEditor to make the object editable.   The question isn't documented well enough to give specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not own the code describing the class and can not add attributes to it you can add an `ExpandableObjectConverter` associated with the generic `object`.

```
TypeConverterAttribute ObjectAttribute = new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(ExpandableObjectConverter));
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(object), ObjectAttribute);
```